# Lazreport - how to export to excel?

Tags: export, reporting, export-to-excel, lazarus

I created a report using LazReport (freepascal). I need to get this into Excel.

I tried saving the resulting report file (.frp) but I can't seem to find any app that opens it.

Then I thought it would be good to get this into Excel. But I can't seem to find any doc or instructions on how to do this. Has anyone found a solution to this and if so please share the answer here. If I have one simple example or steps that would suffice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add frCSVExport in your form and when you show report click save and choice CSV format to save

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was pretty easy showing the report and saving it as CSV. Howerver, it doesn't seem to work correctly. My report has headings, column headings, etc. and then the data. The csv file only contains data without the rest of the info. Is there a way to get all info to show? Thanks!